# Ruby on Rails, add form fields for Order class before Order is created?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I want to ask some fellow Ruby/Rails devs if this is even possible. Here's the scenario:

I have an ecommerce app using [spree](http://spree.com). This app lets you view a product page and click "Add To Cart" while specifying a quantity. This button triggers a function to create an order (if none existed before):

```
# orders_controller.rb
# Adds a new item to the order (creating a new order if none already exists)
def populate
  populator = Spree::OrderPopulator.new(current_order(create_order_if_necessary: true), current_currency)
  puts "current order = #{current_order}"
  if populator.populate(params[:variant_id], params[:quantity])
    respond_with(@order) do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to cart_path }
    end
  else
    flash[:error] = populator.errors.full_messages.join(" ")
    redirect_back_or_default(spree.root_path)
  end
end
```

I want to customize this, such that a user can create a custom order. This custom order would have additional fields: a custom message and a photo upload. My ideal workflow would be.

1. User clicks "custom order" on product page.
2. Modal opens. There they can enter in a text field and upload an image. Then click "add to cart" (still within the modal).
3. Get redirected to the cart page where they can either checkout or continue shopping.

I'm hoping that I can achieve this workflow, but I fear it isn't possible without seriously hacking up my orders controller. Can anyone think of a way that I can store this custom order data before the order class is actually created? Is this where a NoSQL type storage could be a solution?

Thanks!

**EDIT**: I realize that I ought to include the html code that renders the add-to-cart button. It appears that the code I'm using might just work on it's own. Notice at the top of the file it initiates a form with the @orders model (even though it hasn't been created yet:

```
#_cart_form.html.erb
<%= form_for :order, :url => populate_orders_path do |f| %>
<div id="inside-product-cart-form" data-hook="inside_product_cart_form" itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
<% if @product.price_in(current_currency) and !@product.price.nil? %>
  <div data-hook="product_price" class="columns five <% if !@product.has_variants? %> alpha <% else %> omega <% end %>">

    <div id="product-price">

      <div>
        <span class="price selling" itemprop="price">
          <%= display_price(@product) %>
        </span>
        <span itemprop="priceCurrency" content="<%= @product.currency %>"></span>
      </div>

      <% if @product.master.can_supply? %>
        <link itemprop="availability" href="http://schema.org/InStock" />
      <% elsif @product.variants.empty? %>
        <br />
        <span class="out-of-stock"><%= Spree.t(:out_of_stock) %></span>
      <% end %>
    </div>

      <% if @product.master.can_supply? %>

        <div class="add-to-cart">
          <%= number_field_tag :quantity, 1, :class => 'title', :min => 1 %>
          <%= button_tag :class => 'btn btn-success', :id => 'add-to-cart-button', :type => :submit do %>
            <%= Spree.t(:add_to_cart) %>
          <% end %>
        </div>
      <% elsif @product.variants.empty? %>

      <% end %>
  </div>
<% else %>
    <div id="product-price">
      <br>
      <div><span class="price selling" itemprop="price"><%= Spree.t('product_not_available_in_this_currency') %></span></div>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I have setup the new field on the orders table in my sql db so im going to test if that works to just throw it in here.

**Another Edit** I tested this and I get the following output in the command line (after I click add to cart in my modal):

```
Started POST "/store/orders/populate" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-05-20 22:37:30 -0400
Processing by Spree::OrdersController#populate as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"oD+iQ9av7+nynOisuGdcHDrxCBZxghtKq2uE/slpeyA=", "variant_id"=>"16", "order"=>{"custom_product_image"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007fea642992c0 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/yj/hkslby052mxc7yn27ljx8fbh0000gp/T/RackMultipart20150520-2771-1f52ot9>, @original_filename="coffee1.jpeg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"order[custom_product_image]\"; filename=\"coffee1.jpeg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">, "custom_product_description"=>"test"}, "quantity"=>"1", "button"=>""}
```

My new custom fields are `custom_product_description` and `custom_product_image`. They are both being included in this POST message, however in the resulting SQL statements that get executed it is not being updated in the SQL table. Can someone tell me what the missing step is here? The fields are being passed as params in a POST, but what do I need to do with them to get that to insert values into my Postgres SQL?

Comment: If I understand your question, the answer is definitely yes.  Unfortunately I am signing off for the night, but if you can explain where you have doubts, I (or someone else) can try to point you in the right direction.  For instance, I am currently working on an application where a modal is launched, data is gathered and through AJAX the current page is updated with based on the data.

Comment: That definitely sounds like something I could do. I'm sure there are a few ways to do it. I found something in my current app that might change potential answers. Will edit my question in a sec.

Comment: OK GL @Haymaker.  Let us know if you get stuck.

Comment: Alright have an update. Will post in the answer.